# Relating discrete logs with two different modulus.

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Assume $p$ is a prime.

Assume $g$ is primitive root for both $\Bbb Z_p$ and $\Bbb Z_{2p}$.

We know in discrete logarithm problem $z$ is unique mod $p-1$ in $g^z=h\bmod p$.

Then we know that $g^z=h + kp$ for some $k\in\Bbb Z$ and wlog $0\leq z\leq(p-1)$ holds.

Is it true that then $g^z=(h+ rp)\bmod (2p)$ holds where $r=k\bmod (2p)$?

So is $z$ discrete log of $h+rp$ in $\Bbb Z_{2p}$ as well (seems to be true since  $0\leq z\leq2p-1$ holds as well)?

So such a $z$ is unique for mod $(2p-1)$ in $g^z=(h+ rp)\bmod (2p)$?

Vice versa if $g^{y}=w\bmod 2p$ then is either $y'=y$ or $y'=y-(p-1)$ hold in $g^{y'}=w\mod p$?

Comment: There are complications, for $g$ need not even be a primitive root of $p^2$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I replaced $p^2$ by $p+2$ could you please confirm this version too?

Comment: Please don't radically change the content of a question.

Comment: @GregMartin this is not a radical change at all. I just replaced $p^2$ by $p+2$ and I expect similar verdict.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen sorry about the change I do not expect this to be drastic change. Is the verdict here also same as prior?